# Facebook App Secure URL

Tags: facebook, https, hosting, facebook-apps

I have builded succesufuly an online app hosted on 000webhost free hosting service
Then i wanted to link the facebook app that i have created to the webhost Link:
The Link works:
http://androidarabia.web44.net/App.php?oem=samsung&country=Lebanon
but it the facebook appp require a secure canvas url when i write the link just with https it does not work but in sandbox mode just in the normal url it works perfectly
Please advice for any solution to a way to host my app to https server
Thank you
Please add comment for further explanation or information needed

Comment: Probably can't do it with that free hosting service. I think heroku provides free ssl hosting, and has some sort of relationship to FB, so thats probably your best bet.

Comment: @ZachL Ok thanks i will try heroku but whenever i register using the Facebook Link and my email it say sorry an error has occurred please try again later if you have some sort of a link to sign up to that hosting you will do me a big favor and thanks for your effort man :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution thank to Zachl it was using the Heroku web hosting that have SSL(HTTPS) support for Facebook.
Thanks All for your effort And Thanks Zachl